# Deserialising aws struct to string mapping

Tags: go, aws-sdk

I'm trying to deserialize an AWS struct in go so that I can pass in parameters and output values based on those parameters, for example;

```
func DisplayResults(conf *config.Configuration,
regionalData []*ec2.DescribeInstancesOutput) {

  log.Debug("Displaying results")
  log.Debug("Table view [%v]", conf.Display)

  for _, rv := range regionalData {
    for _, reservation := range rv.Reservations {
      for _, instance := range reservation.Instances {
        var i map[string]interface{}
        json.Unmarshal(instance, i)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried using:

```
"github.com/fatih/structs"
```

```
i := structs.Map(instance)
log.Print("%v", i)
```

however, I think that I need to somehow derefence the struct because my output looks like this:

```
RamdiskId:<nil> SriovNetSupport:<nil> VpcId:0xc420321ba0 State:map[Code:0xc42031ea08 Name:0xc420321890] VirtualizationType:0xc420321b90 CapacityReservationId:<nil> ClientToken:0xc420321560 HibernationOptions:map[Configured:0xc42031e96b] IamInstanceProfile:map[Arn:0xc4203215a0 Id:0xc4203215b0] ImageId:0xc4203215c0
```

I've also tried this:

```
  func DisplayResults(conf *config.Configuration, regionalData []*ec2.DescribeInstancesOutput, parameters []string) {
  log.Debug("Displaying results")
  log.Debug("Table view [%v]", conf.Display)

  for _, rv := range regionalData {
    for _, reservation := range rv.Reservations {
      for _, instance := range reservation.Instances {
          y := deref(instance)

         log.Print("%v", y["InstanceId"])
      }
    }
  }
}

  func deref(instance *ec2.Instance) ec2.Instance {
  var i ec2.Instance
  x := &i
  *x = *instance
  return i
 }
```

Comment: What makes you think you need to unmarshal an instance? From what I see it is already a struct that can be used as is.

Comment: My aim is that I can pass in parameters such as ipv4, or instance id dynamically and only return values for those struct values, I didnt want to write an if statement for each parameter if that makes sense